# Looping Linkbutton and Label using dataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I am trying to search the database using `DataList` and `ItemTemplate`.

I just want to loop the data from database in a `linkbutton` and a `label` row by row.

I am new to this
Thanks in Advance

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Auctionno", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Location", typeof(string)));
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Auction_Upload where Keyword = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);

con.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if(dr.Read())
{
    DataRow dc = dt.NewRow();
    dc["Description"] = dr["Description"].ToString();
    dc["Auctionno"] = dr["Auctionno"].ToString();
    dc["Location"] = dr["Location"].ToString();
    dt.Rows.Add(dc);
}

DataList1.DataSource = dt;
DataList1.DataBind();
```

aspx code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" Width="600">
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <br /> 
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Font-Names="Raleway,sans-serif" Font-Size="15" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Auctionno") %>' /> 
        <br /> 
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" Font-Size="12" Font-Names="Raleway,sans-serif" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Description") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: You're doing it fine, what is the problem?

Comment: I need to get all the values from database in a linkbutton and a lable. But the problem is, only the  first row is displaying

Comment: Show the aspx code where you're binding it to the `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" Width="600">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <br />
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Font-Names="Raleway,sans-serif" Font-Size="15" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Auctionno") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" Font-Size="12" Font-Names="Raleway,sans-serif" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Description") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>

Comment: Are you sure your query returns more than one row?

Comment: no it is returning only the first row

Comment: Then its obvious, your DataList shows that one row :)

Comment: i need to display more than one row

Comment: what if i have two rows in which a column has same data in it. How to use where clause and display both the data. I mean both the row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the if to a While and you will get your rows, as you only read one row at a time using datareader.Read()

```
while(dr.Read())
{
    DataRow dc = dt.NewRow();
    dc["Description"] = dr["Description"].ToString();
    dc["Auctionno"] = dr["Auctionno"].ToString();
    dc["Location"] = dr["Location"].ToString();
    dt.Rows.Add(dc);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to Session a Eval value?

Comment: I Think so , if you make a method   something like , Mymethod(Eval("mydata"))    , and in mymethod you set the session

Comment: Great @Thorarins ! I didn't notice it

Answer (score 0):

As you said in the comments your existing query returns only one row, so this is the reason your DataList shows only one row.

If you want to get all rows from database, change the query and fetch them all

```
select * from Auction_Upload /*just remove the WHERE clause*/
```

Everything else is perfectly fine.

Comment: Silly mistake. I didnt notice that. Thanks

Comment: what if i have two rows in which a column has same data in it. How to use where clause and display both the data. I mean both the row

Comment: You can simply use where condition on that column `WHERE yourcolumnname = 'anydata'`. How many rows it matches, it'll return them all., because you're not using `distinct` so it'll give duplicate entries too.

Comment: I have changed if to while and it worked. any ways thanks for your help

Comment: Is it possible to Session a Eval value?